# Funneling air into a small opening, calculating time of speed differential

Tags: acceleration, speed, air

1. Assume I have a funnel that fits a rectangle air vent of 1" x 4" with an opening for a circular tube of 0.5" diameter. After connecting a 0.5" diameter x 2 ft tube to the funnel, the air vent blows air through the tube, but the air coming out from the other end of the tube is much weaker than without the funnel and the tube. Shouldn't all the air from the vent be funneled into this tube causing a greater force of air through the tube?

---

2. Assume I have a small Lidar range finder mounted from my object X, which is moving forward at the speed of SX, to accurately measure the distance DX between X and object Y in front, which is also moving forward at the speed of SY. How do I calculate how fast (rate of change) and how much (total difference) SX needs to decrease or increase to become equivalent to SY so that X can reach a fixed distance DY behind Y where DY is how far Y would travel in N seconds (and also how far X would travel in N seconds once SX = SY)?